# Python Traitlets error in validate_elements running JupyterHub

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, jupyterhub

After making seemingly unrelated changes and redeploying JupyterHub to OpenShift, I'm seeing a new error in the log from the pod, which blocks JupyterHub from spawning a notebook.

The configuration file did not change. The curious thing about the error is that it seems to be saying that the issue is that it is expecting a trait to be a 'tuple' but it got a type of 'tuple'.

The core part of the error log:

```
File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 2254, in validate_elements
self.element_error(obj, v, self._trait)
File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 2233, in element_error
raise TraitError(e)
traitlets.traitlets.TraitError: Element of the 'profiles' trait of a ProfilesSpawner instance must be a tuple, but a value of ('Jupyter Project - Minimal Notebook', 'minimal-notebook', 'kubespawner.KubeSpawner', {'singleuser_image_spec': 'minimal-notebook:3.6'}) <class 'tuple'> was specified.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [the block starting with this line](https://github.com/ipython/traitlets/blob/41551bc8b30ccc28af738e93615e3408cb94d5d3/traitlets/traitlets.py#L2832)

If you have per_key_override, then the validate function is failing for value 'v' there. The error message is not very informative as whenever validate function fails (for any reason), it will say the same error message. (Try to blindly raise an error inside validate function and test).

I suggest you check why validate function is failing. I think the data type is ok.